AsyncForwardingAppender - Buffer overflow Log4net c#
Team,
I got the following error frequently when I am using the below appender,
AsyncForwardingAppender - Buffer overflow. 1 logging events have been lost in the last 30 seconds. [BufferSize: 1000]
<appender name="asyncForwarder" type="Log4Net.Async.AsyncForwardingAppender,Log4Net.Async">
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppender" />
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="asyncForwarder" />
</root>

